# Return null instance when constructor parameter is null

Tags: constructor

So I want to have some sort of condition like this:

```
    public Foo( Id baz ){
        if(baz == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            this.entry.baz = baz;
        }
    }
```

Obviously constructors cannot return a value, but I want class instance to be a null if parameters do not match. Does it make sense?

p.s. I don't wanna throw an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor cannot return value, But you can handle it differently.

1. Make your constructor as private
2. Declare a public static method to initialize your constructor using the params provided.

   ```
   private Foo( Id baz ){
       Foo foo=new Foo();
       foo.entry.baz = baz;
   }


   public static Foo getInstance( Id baz){
       if(baz == null){
          return null;
       } else {
           Foo foo=new Foo(baz);
          return foo;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed!

Comment: I was going to recommend this approach but the only thing I'd have to add is that this approach is called **`Factory Pattern`**.